# linbreak text inside div between two fixed width divs

Tags: html, css

My pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/vzuLC

[image]

How can I tell the orange div to line-break its text/content so that the yellow div does not linebreak?

div green and div yellow must have a fixed width. The div between them should have width:auto that means the div grows with the content and breaks with the content.

I do only IE9+ and latest Chrome/FF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set its width with [CSS calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AlsnE)

```
#address{
  width: calc(100% - 100px); 
}
```

[Browser support for calc()](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

Comment: thanks. I have also a solution basing on html table which is ok for me as I display tabular data: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/gimoI

Comment: You don't really need tables at all for this kind of data (only one data column).

Answer (score 0):

@Itay 's answer is great, but I would recommend you use `absolute` position for compatibility reason. For front-end developers, compatibility is everything.

```
.wrapper{ 
  position: relative;
  border-top:white solid 1px;  
  border-bottom:#ddd solid 1px;
}

#alarmNumber{
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  width:50px;
  background:lightgreen;
}
#address{
  float:left;
  margin: 0 50px;
}
#expander{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  background:yellow;
  text-align:center;
  width:50px; 
  height:100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://cdpn.io/AlsnE)

Comment: this i get from your pen: Anonymous Pens Can't Be Viewed in Full Page View

Comment: sorry not familiar with that site, just replace these `CSS` to yours will make the change

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `position:absolute` and  `box-sizing`

```
#alarmNumber{
  float:left;
  width:50px;
  background:lightgreen;
  position:relative; /* add this */
  z-index:1; /* add this so that it appears on top of address */
}
#address{ 
  width:100%; 
  padding: 0 50px; /* add this */
  position:absolute; /* add this */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* add this */
}
```

**[UPDATED CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jxokn)**